# Check if Android filesystem is encrypted

Tags: android, security, encryption, filesystems

We are developing secure application for Android. It's required for users to keep filesystems of their devices encrypted, but we have to check this fact and forbid to use app. Is it possible to check if filesystem is encrypted? Also there are some devices with Android < 3.0 that supports encryption, for example Motorola RAZR. It would be interesting to know about encryption on such devices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your app is registered as [a device admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), you can call `getStorageEncryptionStatus()` on `DevicePolicyManager` to find out the encryption status of the device, for API Level 11 and higher.

For any whole-device encryption on lower API levels, please contact the device manufacturer.

Comment: Any way to figure out if the encryption is software or hardware based? At least in Android 5.1.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii: Beats me, sorry.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#isBoundKeyAlgorithm(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 15):

Just to clarify CommonsWare's answer, you can *read* the device encryption status without any Android permissions.

```
/**
 * Returns the encryption status of the device. Prior to Honeycomb, whole device encryption was
 * not supported by Android, and this method returns ENCRYPTION_STATUS_UNSUPPORTED.
 *
 * @return One of the following constants from DevicePolicyManager:
 * ENCRYPTION_STATUS_UNSUPPORTED, ENCRYPTION_STATUS_INACTIVE,
 * ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVATING, ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE,
 * ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_KEY, ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE_PER_USER.
 */
@TargetApi(11)
private static int getDeviceEncryptionStatus(Context context)
{
    int status = DevicePolicyManager.ENCRYPTION_STATUS_UNSUPPORTED;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        final DevicePolicyManager dpm =
                (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        if (dpm != null) {
            status = dpm.getStorageEncryptionStatus();
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

See the documentation for [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager) and the [encryption status flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVATING).

It's also worth mentioning that Android has moved from full-disk encryption
to file-based encryption to support Direct Boot, among other things.
See [File Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based).

Comment: This code does not appear to work on my 2013 model Nexus 7. In this case, it appears as though even when I have taken steps to encrypt the device, dpm.getStorageEncryptionStatus() returns ENCRYPTION_STATUS_INACTIVE.

Answer (score 5):

to clarify previous answers
on API < 23 `getStorageEncryptionStatus()` returns `ENCRYPTION_STATUS_INACTIVE` when device is encrypted but passcode was't enabled.

On API >= 23 it returns `ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_KEY` in this case.

Comment: ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_KEY is not being returned on Samsung devices, e.g. S7 with Android 6 if the PIN for starting the device is not defined.