# Require device to be encrypted prior to app install

Tags: android, encryption, android-install-apk

I have seen various [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640708/check-if-android-filesystem-is-encrypted) on how to check if an android file system is encrypted or not at application runtime.

What I'm looking to do is prevent application installation unless the device is encrypted. **Is this possible?** If not, I think the only thing I could do is check the encryption status in my main activity (and boot services), and exit the activity / close the service if it's not encrypted.

I have explored the [App Manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible?

No.

> If not, I think the only thing I could do is check the encryption status in my main activity (and boot services), and exit the activity / close the service if it's not encrypted.

That is possible, using `DevicePolicyManager` and [`getStorageEncryptionStatus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getStorageEncryptionStatus%28%29). Though you may want to at least explain to the user, in your activity, why the user cannot use your app.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely provide a user prompt indicating that it could not be done.