# How to check Cryptography on Android with java

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

For my app to be used, I want first, to check if the user has the smartphone encrypted.
I know where to find the information on the phone: "Security and Lock Screen > Device Security > Cipher and Credentials" (or something like this, my smartphone language is not in english). There, I can see that the status is encrypted and the goal is to reach this information with java code on my app. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up founding a solution here: [Check if Android filesystem is encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640708/check-if-android-filesystem-is-encrypted)

This is how I applied it:

```
Integer encrypt_status = 0;
final DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if (dpm != null) {
        Integer status = dpm.getStorageEncryptionStatus();
        if(status == DevicePolicyManager.ENCRYPTION_STATUS_INACTIVE || status == DevicePolicyManager.ENCRYPTION_STATUS_UNSUPPORTED){
            encrypt_flag = 1;
        }
    }
```